# How to update to NULL a field in solr using XML?

Tags: solr, null, updates, solr4

In solr 4 is possible to make partial document updates. For example:

```
<add>
 <doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field update="set" name="myfield">newvalue</field>
 </doc>
</add>
```

updates myfield to "newvalue" in record 1 without affecting other fields.
But how can I update myfield to NULL?

I tried with

```
<field update="set" name="myfield"></field>
```

but obviously it sets an empty string (not NULL) and for date fields raises an error.

Is there a way to do this without updating whole document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Atomic Update documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates#Available_Modifiers) for the set command, you need to set the `null="true"` attribute on the field.

```
<add>
 <doc>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field update="set" name="myfield" null="true" />
 </doc>
</add>
```

Comment: The example you provided doesn't work because sets field to "null" string. Thanks however for the link. According to the documentation right syntax is: `<field update="set" name="myfield" null="true"/>`